# Loading Grunt tasks from Submodule

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Is it possible to install a Grunt plugin and inherit it's tasks with the option to override them?

E.g:

`grunt-module-a` has config for the following tasks:

`default
serve
install
deploy
config`

`grunt-module-b` has done `npm install grunt-module-a`, I want running grunt here to inherit the tasks listed above with the option to override their config.

How would this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you haven't found the answer yet and/or somebody stumbling upon this (i just fixed this in one of my projects with a similar problem):

https://github.com/tusbar/grunt-subgrunt